# How to properly use Enums with multiple values

Tags: java, swing

New to Java and trying to get my head around how I could properly use Enums in this scenario;

User selects his model from a Combobox dropdown, e.g.

```
comboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] {
  ...
  Focus,
  Mondeo,
  Fiesta,
  ...
}));
```

I then need to find a way to get the carId for the string the user selected in my Enum:

```
public enum Ford{
 ...
 FOCUS("Focus", 26),
 MONDEO("Mondeo", 6),
 FIESTA("Fiesta", 13),
 ...
 ;

 private final String name;
 private final int carId;
}
```

I was thinking of using some kind of comparitor loop, which tries to match the string collected to the Ford.name, and if it matches, return the carId:

```
    public String getCarId() {
    String selectedItem = comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    for (Ford c : Ford.values()) {
        if (c.name().equals(selectedItem)) {
            return c.carId
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

However I'm not sure how to proceed / fix my problem.

Is my logic all off or am I on the right track at all?

Comment: How are you even calling this? `Ford` isn't a valid enum class. provide the full class please.

Comment: Don't use a `String[]` array as the basis for your JComboBox model but rather use one that holds your enum. Then use a cell renderer to render the enum properly in the JComboBox. Then the selection will bring all the information to you.

Comment: What Hovercraft said. For the record however, all enums have a static valueOf() method taking the name of an enum constant as argument and returning the corresponding constant. But you're returning an int or a boolean from a method whose return type is String, so I would advise taking some time learning about types in general.

Comment: Also note that enums have a `.values()` method that returns an array that holds all the enum values.

Comment: Ahhh @HovercraftFullOfEels I see! I will give this a shot now :)

Comment: Ah yes @JBNizet, I was being sloppy, been tunnel-vision'ing trying to figure out a solution :D

Comment: Apologies @BasilBourque, it's Swing

Answer (score 4):

## Keep track of the enum object, not its label

Keep a reference to the [enum object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) selected by the user, rather than a reference to the string of the enum object’s display name.

```
// Display combobox
// User picks an item.
// Your event-handling code reacts by remembering which *object* not *string* was select.
Ford fordSelectedByUser = … ;  // You pull reference from the data model backing your widget.
```

I do not know what combobox widget you are using. In the [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) framework, for example, a [combobox](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-combobox.html) is backed by a data model of objects. Perhaps you are using Swing? I no longer recall the details of how Swing works, but glancing at [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer), it looks like you can back the combobox with objects and use a custom renderer.

### `JComboBox< Ford >`, not `JComboBox< String >`

**Make a `JComboBox` that holds `Ford` objects**, not `String` objects. You can get an array of all your enum values by calling `values()`. That method is a strange one, not listed on the JavaDoc of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) though mentioned in [`Enum.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)) method doc – it is an “implicit” method, but I don’t think we care about the gory technical details there.

```
Ford[] fords = Ford.values() ; // Get array of all the objects defined by this enum.
JComboBox< Ford > fordsComboBox = new JComboBox( fords );
```

Track the selected `Ford` object selected, not its display name.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    JComboBox cb = ( JComboBox )e.getSource() ;
    Ford selectedFord = ( Ford )cb.getSelectedItem() ;  // Is casting still needed, or is Swing Generics-aware? Maybe: Ford selectedFord = ( JComboBox< Ford > )e.getSource().getSelectedItem() ;
    updateLabel( selectedFord.getDisplayName() ) ;
}
```

Your custom renderer calls the enum `Ford` object’s `getDisplayName` method that you will write.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

public enum Ford {

    FOCUS( "Ford" , 26 ),
    MONDEO( "Mondeo" , 6 ),
    FIESTA( "Fiesta" , 13 );

    private final String displayName;
    private final int id;

    // Constructor
    Ford ( String name , int carId ) {
        this.displayName = name;
        this.id = carId;
    }

    // Getters
    public String getDisplayName ( ) {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public int getId ( ) {
        return this.id;
    }

    // `Object` methods
    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Ford{ " +
                "id=" + id +
                ", displayName='" + displayName + '\'' +
                " }";
    }

}
```

Tips:

- Throughout your code base, use `Ford` objects, not a mere integer of its ID number nor a mere string of its display name. This makes your code more self-documenting, provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures valid values.
- To collect a subset of `Enum` objects, use [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) or [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) classes. These are high-performance low-memory implementations of the `Set` and `Map` interfaces.
- Remember an `Enum` is only appropriate if the domain, the set of all possible values, is known at compile-time. Adding or eliminating any of the cars means editing your `Ford` enum class and re-compiling.

  - In contrast, if your app can add more `Ford` cars during runtime, or eliminate any, then you cannot use an `Enum`. You would make `Ford` a regular class rather than a subclass of `Enum`, and would instantiate them as we do any [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) and [collect them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

Comment: Thank you so much for all this Basil! It's quite late here so I will try this tomorrow! Super excited!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate on all the values because you can easily get the enum value in O(1) with [Enum.valueOf(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)).

In your case, `Ford.valueOf(comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()).getCarId()`
should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it correctly enough already, just some minor changes

```
public enum Ford {
     FOCUS("Ford", 26),
     MONDEO("Mondeo", 6),
     FIESTA("Fiesta", 13);

     private final String name; //Good
     private final int carId; //Good


    /** This is a constructor for the enum variable */
    Ford(String name, int carId) {
        this.name = name; //stores the name variable for the enum
        this.carId = carId;
    }


    public int getCarId() { 
        return this.carId; //gets the carID from the enum variable
    }

    public String getCarName() { 
        return this.name; //gets the car name from the enum variable
    }
}
```

To use this enum class, and its values here is an example

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /** This is how you reference an enum value directly */
        System.out.println("Type: " + Ford.FOCUS 
                    + ", Name: " + Ford.FOCUS.getCarName() 
                    + ", ID: " + Ford.FOCUS.getCarId());


        /** This is how you can cycle through all of the values in this enum class */

        for (final Ford f : Ford.values())
            System.out.println("Type: " + f 
                    + ", Name: " + f.getCarName() 
                    + ", ID: " + f.getCarId());

    }
```

Also, note that in java, the keyword "this" is used to reference a global variable that is a member of the class/enum that "this" is being used in. It means "this class's member"